# Why the regular expression matches input but the alert still happens?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I made a simple page to validate input. but even my input matches the regular expressions, all three alerts still happen. Could you please help me figure it out? Thanks

```
<script>
function validate() {

    var tel = document.getElementById("tel").innerHTML;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").innerHTML;
    var pcode = document.getElementById("pcode").innerHTML;
    
    var tvalid = /^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})$/;
    if(!tvalid.test(tel)) {
        alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
    }
    
    if (!(/@gmail\.com$/.test(email)) && !(/@hotmail\.com$/.test(email))  && !(/@outlook\.com$/.test(email)) ) {
         alert("Not a valid email");

    }

    var pvalid = /^([A-Z][A-Z]\d{2}-[a-z]\d[A-Z]\d)$/;
    if(!pvalid.test(pcode)){
         alert("Not a valid postal code.");

    }
    

}
</script>
```

html

```
    <label for="tel">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Format: 001-123-456-7890" required><br>
    <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Format: 001-123-456-7890" required><br>
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="xxx@(gmail/hotmail/outlook).com" required><br>
    <label for="pcode">Postal Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="pcode" name="pcode" placeholder="AA11-c1V2"><br>
    <button type = "button" id="submit" onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code returns invalid for all inputs is because youre not actually testing it against the entered input, rather an empty string `''`.

`.innerHTML` will return an empty string since there is no HTML between the start and end of your `input` tags.
To get the value of a control try using something like `var tel = document.getElementById("tel").value;`
This will return the actual user input.

So your code should look like this:

```js
function validate() {

  var tel = document.getElementById("tel").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var pcode = document.getElementById("pcode").value;

  var tvalid = /^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})$/;
  if (!tvalid.test(tel)) {
    alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
  }

  if (!(/@gmail\.com$/.test(email)) && !(/@hotmail\.com$/.test(email)) && !(/@outlook\.com$/.test(email))) {
    alert("Not a valid email");

  }

  var pvalid = /^([A-Z][A-Z]\d{2}-[a-z]\d[A-Z]\d)$/;
  if (!pvalid.test(pcode)) {
    alert("Not a valid postal code.");

  }


}
```

```html
<label for="tel">Phone Number</label>
<input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Format: 001-123-456-7890" required><br>
<input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Format: 001-123-456-7890" required><br>
<label for="email">Email Address</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="xxx@(gmail/hotmail/outlook).com" required><br>
<label for="pcode">Postal Code</label>
<input type="text" id="pcode" name="pcode" placeholder="AA11-c1V2"><br>
<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Should have noticed that long ago. problem fixed.